# Java Program putting "null" in a text file instead of my string

Tags: java, file, null

EDIT: I understand what the issue is now. I was creating a new instance of the class which reset the values of the variables inside of it. For anyone wondering you can use 'static' for the value of a variable to stay the same throughout all instance of the class
Example: `public static int example = 10;`

I am trying to add a string to a text file, however when I add the string it puts "null" in the file instead of my string. The string is "listName"

Class where my a value is set to the string:

```
public class NewList {

private String listName;

public void newList() {

    System.out.println("NEW LIST");
    System.out.print("List Name: ");

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    setListName(scanner.next());

    System.out.println(listName);

    ListsWriter listsWriterObject = new ListsWriter();
    listsWriterObject.listsWriter();
}

public String getListName() {
    return listName;
}

public void setListName(String listName) {
    this.listName = listName;
}
```

Class where the string is added to the text file:

```
public class ListsWriter {

public void listsWriter() {
    NewList newListObject = new NewList();
    File lists = new File("lists.txt");

    try{
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(lists, true));
        pw.append(newListObject.getListName() + "\n");
        pw.close();
    }catch(IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You just created `newListObject` and you wonder why field `listName` is null?!?!? Don't you think you need to call `setListName()` first, if you want a non-null value?

Comment: `public void newList()` is not constructor, but method which you never invoked. We know it is not constructor because: (1) it has specified return type - here `void`, (2) it doesn't have same name as class which contains it, Java is case sensitive so `NewList` != `newList`

Comment: Call the method after construction. Don't make the mistake of putting all that business logic in the constructor.

Comment: Others seem to believe you thought method `newList()` was a constructor, automatically called when you did `new NewList()`. I can't get myself to believe that, because that method prompts for the `List Name:`, and if you had thought the method was a constructor, why didn't the lack of such prompt automatically tell you that the method isn't executed? I'm sorry, that doesn't seem in any way logical. If you expect name in file to come from a prompt, and running code doesn't prompt you, why are you surprised what name in file is null???

Comment: I wasn't trying to make it a constructor. Im kinda new to java so I don't really know what I'm supposed to do to fix this.

Comment: @Andreas the code did prompt me. In the console it said, "List Name: " and I typed the name in and hit enter... Then the code inputted exactly what I typed into the console and put null in the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the order how your code is executed. You start with your `scanner` stuff and save the name inside the variable `private String listName;`. This variable belongs to the instance of the class `NewList` you are currently in. It is important to note that if you create other instances of `NewList` then they will all have their own `listName` variables.

Next you create `ListsWriter` and call its method. There you try to read the list name with `newListObject.getListName()` however you use `NewList newListObject = new NewList();` before. This will create a **new instance** of `NewList`. It has its own `listName` variable, it is not the same than the variable of the other instance! Thus it is `null`.

If you want the name of the other instance you need to pass either the value or a reference to this instance to the `ListsWriter` object.

You can do this by using a constructor for `ListsWriter` that accepts a `String` as parameter (or a reference to a `NewList` object). Or you add the parameter to the method `listsWriter`.

For example:
`public void listsWriter(String listName) {`

Answer (score 1):

Okay! so I have modified your code you can use it :)
NewList.java

```
public class NewList {

private String listName;

public void newList() {
    System.out.println("NEW LIST");
    System.out.print("List Name: ");

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    listName = scanner.next();

    System.out.println(listName);

    ListsWriter listsWriterObject = new ListsWriter();
    listsWriterObject.listsWriter(listName);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
        new NewList().newList();
}
}
```

ListsWriter.java

```
public class ListsWriter {

public void listsWriter(String listName) {
    File lists = new File("lists.txt");

    try{
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(lists, true));
        pw.append(listName + "\n");
        pw.close();
    }catch(IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Thank you! I think I understand why it wasn't working before and this has fixed it.